# Run multiple rsync's at once?

Tags: rsync

I'm moving over about a million of files (800GB, containing) multiple system backups. And it's only running at ~9MB at a time, often. Enough bandwidth, since it can run up to about 50MB/s.

However, sometimes it doesn't. So I was wondering if I can split the source into multiple directories, so I can have multiple rsync's running at once. And in such way so it speeds up the process.

Note: I have to run the command via the Terminal on Mac.

Is such possible?

update: The main directory consists of 2 subdirectories, so we are speaking of just two Rsync processes running at once, each processing hundreds of thousands of files. :)

Comment: You could try the script as suggested in this link. http://superuser.com/a/368480/252686

Comment: The script got to be edited for my use, I can see clearly (source and destination location, for once) but I haven't got a clue where or what lines to be adjusted.

Comment: Well, this one is exactly not parallelizing. But still could help. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44443/47538